# Understanding encodings in HTML

Tags: python, html, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a .html file using BeautifulSoup4 doing the following:

```
data = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.find_all('span')]
```

The code takes all the items in a given table and stores into `data`. I noticed some of the elements in the data contain texts what seems like html entity encoding. An example element:

`data[5]` stores `'CSCI-GA.1144-\u200b001'`

the text I expected was just `CSCI-GA.1144-001'`

In the html file, I find it as `'CSCI-GA.1144-&#8203;001'`

Why does it show differently when I parse, vs when I inspect the html code? And how do I parse the data so it does not take into account these encodings? Is there a way to exclude?

Comment: `&#8203;` is the (decimal) HTML entity for the (Unicode) character U+200B (ZERO WIDTH SPACE).  That character being in your string (as *represented* by `\u200b`) is generally preferable to having some escape sequence, but you could of course convert back to HTML entities if you wanted (perhaps along with using [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html)).